# make data as per jquery ajax data method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Am doing doing, Edit in place using jquery, if my snippet is too complicated, refer easiest one,

```
'column2' => "RAJANgsfdgf"
'column3' => "SRARDHAMgsdfgdf"
'column4' => "40043433"
'column7' => "23-01-2011 08:00:00"
'column5' => "400e"
'column6' => "1503"
```

i want to make this into somthing like

```
 ( {column2 :"RAJANgsfdgf"},{column3 :"SRARDHAMgsdfgdf"},{column4 :"40043433"},{column7 :"23-01-2011 08:00:00"},{column5 :"400e"},{column6 :"1503"})
```

some time my values somthing like this also

```
'column2' => "RAJANgsfdgf"
'column4' => "40043433"
'column7' => "23-01-2011 08:00:00"
'column6' => "1503"
```

then i should form

```
( {column2 :"RAJANgsfdgf"},{column4 :"40043433"},{column7 :"23-01-2011 08:00:00"},{column6 :"1503"})
```

So this somthing like dynamic, What ever , when ever program find some column and its equlent value, then automatically form the data somthing like above,

Am going to give this new data into jquery ajax, that's y am forming fomthing like this,

```
var collection_of_updated_data = common.dump(o.changed);
collection_of_updated_data = jQuery.trim(collection_of_updated_data);


*****************HERE AM GETTING THAT column1 and value******************


alert(collection_of_updated_data);

    $.ajax({
      url: "program_event_ajax_update.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: collection_of_updated_data,
      dataType: "html",
      async:false,
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: Is it just me? or the problem is really not clear. hmm...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you'd like to take an associative array and turn it into a string representation.

json_encode() is a method to do that.  There are implementations for both [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html) (you mention you're using Javascript, but your array syntax looks more like PHP).

Does this look like the right avenue?  (Or am I misinterpreting your original question?)

Comment: can you please include as to why is that the answer? or at least a link to it :)

Comment: I think JSON is the answer because the right way to pass info between client and server is in a standard structured representation, and JSON is one of the easiest and best to work with. 

The structure being passed is, essentially, JSON, so why re-invent the wheel when there's a perfectly good existing representation? You could also use XML, etc. etc. but no need to create a non-standard representation and then write extra code when there are reliable encode/decoede mechanisms in both JavaScript and PHP already.